# error: Unexpected. Please try again when querying multiple tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a join query, where one of the tables has many nested repeated fields. The query fails if I don't limit the result, either by using limit clause or where clause.

One example:

Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: **job_43582ec20d594ff6b5b97726dd7dbf31**

The same query succeeds if I add a "limit 100" clause.

I thought that I need to use "join each" instead of join, but this didn't change anything.

How can I fix the probelm?

Comment: If you post the query, someone can probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed after changing the join order (small table on left side, big table on right side of join), and using "join each". Seems like a bug as join operation needs to be symmetric.